Can the supremum involving the semi-norm $\|\bullet\|_{A}$ of $\Sigma_d({\mathbb R})$ be attained in any arbitrary $q,n$
Let $d > 1$ be given. The Gelfand-Shilov space $\Sigma_d({\mathbb R})$ consists of those functions $f\in C^\infty({\mathbb R})$ with the property that
$$
 \|f\|_{A}:= \sup_{x\in {\mathbb R}}\sup_{n,q\in {\mathbb N}_0}\left(1+|x|\right)^q|f^{(n)}(x)|\frac{A^{n+q}}{n!^d q!^d} < \infty$$ for every $A> 0.$
It is not hard to see that the supremum above is in fact a maximum (depending on $f$), and that if $f\in \Sigma_d({\mathbb R})$ then, $p f^{(h)}\in \Sigma_d({\mathbb R})$ for all $h\in\mathbb{N}$ and polynomial $p$.
My conjecture: given $A>0$ and a pair of natural numbers $n,q$, there is a function $f\in \Sigma_d({\mathbb R})$ such that $$\|f\|_{A}= \sup_{x\in {\mathbb R}} \left(1+|x|\right)^q|f^{(n)}(x)|\frac{A^{n+q}}{n!^d q!^d}$$.
Is it correct?
